# Tracing wires through conduit

Tags: electrical

[image: Photo for folks to see]I have this junction box that I traced all the wires to and as you will notice there are three wires that are taped off and look dormant (I have not tested to see if these are live). (red, blue, green) they can do it runs up into the attic and due to the insulation I am not able to find out where they can do it runs to. I know that there's a small chance it's hooked up to the meter outside because they are all being used already. I'm not sure where they would be going though if that wasn’t the case . Does anyone know how I can trace them?

Comment: "they can do it runs" You use this phrase twice. What does it mean? "there's a small chance it's hooked up to the meter outside because they are all being used already" but, you said they're not in use, so what does this mean? Please [edit] your question with the mindset of your reader who hasn't a clue what you're talking about except for _exactly_ what you're saying and clarify it so someone who _isn't you_ can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Code requires that all junction boxes remain accessible.

Therefore there must not be any junction boxes which are inaccessible.

If the attic is full of loose insulation, you may have to muck around up there looking for junction boxes.  But the boxes aren't allowed to be buried any worse than that.